# URL Redirects in Wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

Hi folks i'm hoping somebody can help me work this out.

I am trying to create redirects in my site for old external links where my base category has changed.

Example of old external inbound link

[www.mysite.com/whitepaper/my-post](http://www.mysite.com/whitepaper/my-post)

Example of new post URL

[www.mysite.com/tools/instructions/my-post](http://www.mysite.com/tools/instructions/my-post)

I tried a re-direct with RegEx like so

Source /whitepaper/.*
Target /tools/instructions/

So any old posts which were previously /whitepaper/ automatically got to /tools/instuctions/

But i can't find a way to actually append the original post name to the re-direct.

Does that make sense ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't replace all the old URLs with the new URL structure?

Comment: @JarmoT yes, they want the old and new to remain for inbound shared links to prevent 404s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to put this inside .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^whitepaper/(.*)$ /tools/instructions/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here how this works (Explanation)

**^whitepaper/(.*)$** matches URLs that start with "whitepaper/" followed by any characters (captured using (.*)).

**$1** in the replacement URL represents the captured part of the old URL (the part after "whitepaper/").

**[R=301,L**] indicates that this is a permanent (301) redirection and that it should be the last rule applied **(L)**.